# Maximum Likelihood vs. Restricted Maximum Likelihood vs. Penalized Maximum Likelihood vs. Pseudo Likelihood

Tags: probability, distributions, maximum-likelihood, model

I am trying to better understand the differences between the **Maximum Likelihood vs. Restricted Maximum Likelihood vs. Penalized Maximum Likelihood vs. Pseudo Likelihood**. In general, here is what I understand so far:

- The Maximum Likelihood Estimator estimates the most likely value of the model parameters that could have produced the data you have observed.
- The Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimator is similar to the Maximum Likelihood Estimator, however the Maximum Likelihood Estimator is said to overestimate the variance of the model parameters resulting in larger confidence intervals on model parameters than to be expected. To remedy this problem, the Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimator uses a slightly different formula that results in "tighter bounds" on the confidence intervals of model parameters, but the estimates of the model parameters remain more or less identical when compared to the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (https://towardsdatascience.com/maximum-likelihood-ml-vs-reml-78cf79bef2cf). I have not been able to find an exact formula for the Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimator - but I have read (anecdotally) that it is similar to the Maximum Likelihood Estimator.
- I have not been able to understand the Penalized Maximum Likelihood, but I am guessing that this is like "Penalized Regression" - meaning that a regularization term is added to the Maximum Likelihood Estimator to prevent overfitting?
- I have also heard of the "Quasi Likelihood" - which is apparently used when you suspect that there might be a high amount of "over dispersion" (i.e. variance) in the data.
- Finally, the Pseudo Likelihood is said to be a "simpler" version of the original Likelihood and is said to make parameter estimation easier.

**My Questions:**

- Is there an exact formula that shows how model parameters can be estimated (and solved) using the Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimator?
- If the Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimator provides the same model parameter estimates as the Maximum Likelihood Estimator - but the Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimator is said to provide "better" confidence intervals compared to the Maximum Likelihood Estimator : why hasn't the Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimator replaced the Maximum Likelihood Estimator? For example: If I want to fit a Multivariate Normal Distribution to some data, could I use the Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimator to calculate the entries within the mean vector and the variance-covariance matrix?

**References:**

- https://people.csail.mit.edu/xiuming/docs/tutorials/reml.pdf